# How to remove view sub-menu in electron app for main window

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application

Hi i want to remove 3 options from electron title **menu** they are

1. reload
2. Force reload
3. Toggle developer tools

as shown below

[image]

Here is what i have tried

**background.js**

```
     import { app, session, protocol, BrowserWindow , dialog, ipcMain, Menu} from 'electron'

      const menu = Menu.getApplicationMenu(); // get default menu
      
      console.log('menu %s',menu.items);
    
    
     let menuIndex = menu.items.findIndex(o => {
          return o.role == 'viewmenu'
      })

    //splice items based on names , i'm not able to do that because i cannot see the full json object and its structure in console.log

   //Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);   //set menu
```

Further i don't know what to do

Please help me thanks in advance !!

Comment: is there is no solution for this problem !

Comment: You'll have the redefine the menu yourself.

Comment: @Peterrabbit can't `splice` those menus which i don't want. ?

Comment: What do you mean ? If you define and set the menu you can put in it just what you want, if you need some of the standard items you can put them explicitely, you can use the `role` key for those items, you'll have almost nothing else to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *new* menu based on the default using [`Menu.buildFromTemplate`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu#menubuildfromtemplatetemplate) and pass the default's menu items as template.

Then set that as application menu. During the construction you can cut out elements you don't want

```
const menu = Menu.getApplicationMenu(); // get default menu

// build a new menu based on default one
const newmenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
  menu.items.map(i => {
    // overwrite viewmenu item
    if (i.role === 'viewmenu') {
      // create new submenu
      const newviewsub = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
        i.submenu.items.slice(4) // cut first 4 item (4th is separator)
      )
      // replace this item's submenu with the news
      return Object.assign({}, i, { submenu: newviewsub })
    }
    // otherwise keep
    return i
  })
)

Menu.setApplicationMenu(newmenu)
```

You should see that the 'view' menu's first 3 element is gone
[image: result menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your own menu, it's not that hard:

```
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
  [
    { role: 'appMenu' },
    { role: 'editMenu' },
    {
      label: 'View',
      submenu: [
        { role: 'resetZoom' },
        { role: 'zoomIn' },
        { role: 'zoomOut' },
        { type: 'separator' },
        { role: 'togglefullscreen' }
      ]
    },
    { role: 'windowMenu' },
    {
      role: 'help',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Contact Support',
          click: async () => {
            const { shell } = require('electron')
            await shell.openExternal('https://www.example.com/contact/')
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

See [example in Menu Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu#examples).